# Supporting multiple HTTP methods with single rest inbound gateway

Tags: spring-integration

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="searchRequest"
    reply-channel="searchResponse" 
    http-method="GET" expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
    mapped-response-headers="Content-Type" />
```

I can't see a property like supported-methods of inbound-gateway in the above one, where we can provide multiple methods in a single gateway. Is there a way to achieve the same with single outbound gateway to support multiple http methods?

Answer (score 0):

That is an **outbound** gateway. The inbound gateway has `supported-methods` which is a comma-delimited list of method names.

See [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/http.html#http-namespace)